# Choosing representatives with spatial separation

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

There are $n$ sets of $k$ points in the 2-dimensional plane. Following the recent social distancing instructions, the distance between each two points in the same set is at least 2. We would like to choose a single representative point from each set, such that the distance between each two representatives is at least 2. What is the smallest $k$ (as a function of $n$) for which this is always possible?

For $n=2$, I am quite sure that the answer is 3. $k=2$ is insufficient, as shown below:
[image]

The distance between the green points is 2 and the distance between the blue points is 2, but the distance between each pair of representatives is only $\sqrt{2}$.

I do not have a proof that $k=3$ is sufficient, but in all configurations I tried, I ended up with a situation as shown below:
[image]

If the distance between every two green points is 2, and the distance between every blue and green point is less than 2, then the blue points must be inside a very small region, and then there must be some blue points with a distance of less than 2.

So my question is: given $n$ (the number of sets), what is the minimal $k$ (the number of points in each set) such that there always exist representatives with a sufficient separation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k(n)$ denotes the minimal sufficient $k$ for $n$ sets. A subset of the pane is *$2$-separated*, if the distance between each two disstinct points of the set is at least $2$.

An example where all sets are equal shows that $k(n)\ge n$.

**Example 1**. It seems that  $k(n)\ge n+1$ for each $n\ge 2$.

*Proof*. Consider a regular $2n$-gon such that the distance between its neighbor by one vertices is $2$. Enumerate the vertices of the $n$-gon along its boundary by natural numbers from $1$ to $2n$. As each of sets $A_1,\dots, A_{n-1}$ pick the set of all vertices with odd numbers, and by the set $A_n$ pick the set of all vertices with even numbers. $\square$

**Proposition 1.** For each natural $n$, $k(n+1)\le k(n)+3$.

*Proof*. Given a family $\{A_i:1\le i\le n+1\}$ of $2$-separated sets of size $|k(n)+3|$ each, pick as the first representative a leftmost point $P$ from the union of the sets. Let $P$ represents $A_i$. By Lemma 2, each of the sets $A_j$ contains at most $3$ points at distance less than two from $n$. Let $A_j’$ be the set $A_j$ with these points removed. Then $\{A’_j:j\ne i\}$ is a family of  $n$ $2$-separated sets of size $k(n)$ each, so we can choose a $2$-separated set of representatives for the family. When we add the point $P$ to this set, we obtain a $2$-separated set of representatives for the family $\{A_i\}$.
$\square$

By Lemma 3,  $k(2)\le 3$.

---

The following lemmas can be useful.

**Lemma 1.** An *open* disc of radius $2$ cannot cover six points with a distance at least $2$ between each distinct points.

*Proof.* Let a disc $D$ centered at $O$ with radius $2$ contains points $A_1,\dots, A_6$ in its interior. The rays $OA_i$ partition $D$ into six (maybe, degenerated) sectors, so one of them has the angle at most $\pi/6$. Using an equality
$$|A_iA_j|^2=|OA_i|^2+|OA_j|^2-2|OA_i||OA_j|\cos\angle A_iOA_j$$ is easy to check that the distance between points $A_i$ lying on the rays bounding the sector is less than $2$. $\square$

Similarly we can prove the following

**Lemma 2.** A half of an *open* disc of radius $2$ cannot cover four points with a distance at least $2$ between each distinct points. $\square$

**Lemma 3**. Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be subsets of a plane, $|\mathcal A|=3$, $|\mathcal B|=2$, and a distance between any two distinct points of $\mathcal A$ or of $\mathcal B$ is at least $2$. Then there exist points $A\in\mathcal A$ and $A\in\mathcal B$ such that the distance between $A$ and $B$ is at least $2$.

*Proof*. Suppose to the contrary that a distance between each point $A\in\mathcal A$ and each point $B\in\mathcal B$ is less than $2$. It follows that the set $\mathcal A$ is contained in the interior of a lens created by the circles of radius $2$ centered at points of $\mathcal B$. Since the lens is seen at angle at most $2\pi/3$ from any of these centers, say $B$, there are two distinct points $A'$ and $A’'$ of the set $\mathcal A$ such that the segment $A'A’'$ is seen from $B$ at angle less than $\pi/3$.  Similarly to the end of the proof of Lemma 1, it follows that $|A'A'’|<2$.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks! So now the lower bound is $n+1$ and the upper bound is $3n-3$, right? It is tight for $n=2$, but for $n\geq 3$ there is a gap.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Right, the upper bound follows from an equality $k(2)=3$. The gap for small values is intriguing and I think we should try to tighten them. Also both lower and upper bounds don’t seem to be tight. I think that the topic is interesting and actual and can lead to a good paper published in a respective journal, provided our results are new. But now we have too few results to publish so it would be good to extend them.

Comment: I agree. I will think about it.

Comment: Instead of asking about points, is it equivalent to ask directly about unit discs? I.e.: "there are n sets, each of which contains k pairwise-disjoint unit discs. What is the smallest k(n) such that there always exist n pairwise-disjoint representatives?". 
Similar to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/361214/34461 but with discs instead of squares.